# How understand ImageView Layouting in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

This is maybe a fundamental question, but the following behavior hurts me all the time. So I understand the bellow behavior (almost), but I do not understand why this behavior has been implemented for android.

Topic is about "wrap_content" of one dimension size if the other dimension is fixed.

Here is an example.

[image]

The XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="WrapContent w=wc \& h=wc" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hybrid w=200dp \& h=wc" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hybrid w=wc \& h=200dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Fixed  w=200dp \& h=100dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Just basics stuff.

In the no1, it just wraps content from its own size : ok
In the no4, it wraps the content up to the fixed size : ok
In the no2 et no3, it keeps the own size for the dimension that is wc (!?!), and extends the other dimension to fixed size. It feels(for me, and for my today understanding) like there is a kind of top linearlayout that constraints the size, and then own an Image View. Bref...

Why this behavior ? Is it normal ? Is it expected ? Is it only make trouble to me ?

I know that we can override ImageView on Measure and define a precise layout, I'm doing that, however, in my daily work, I would really need a "wrap content" that wrap the drawable content up the to fixed constraint (of the ImageView or it Parent). Not you ?

I would expect that ImageView wrap it content from it drawable, like this (no2 and no 3)

[image]

Comment: I've read this three times, and I still don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: what you expect for wrap_content?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are saying, but please try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to every `ImageView` and then try it again...

Comment: I agrre with Mike as I am unable to get what you are asking for. WRAP_CONTENT is the attribute that wraps the view to its original size(Image size here). Now if you are giving height as wrap content and width as fixed then simultaneously it will take height of the image and width fixed and vice versa.

Comment: @XaverKapeller thank for this, I didn't know it. So it will help me a lot. Any idea why this is not default as "true"

Comment: My issue is about the fact that when ONE size dimension is fixed, it doesn't adjust it size, but when TWO size dimension are fixed, it does !

Comment: @Anthony Whether the default is true or false doesn't really matter, both do different things. Always using `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` does not make any sense, just like always using `android:adjustViewBounds="false"` doesn't make any sense. It just depends on the situation which ne you need.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I personally expect the default behavior as the main one (ok, what is the main usage is another question).

Comment: @Viren, ok this is probably the root point here, when you say "WRAP_CONTENT is the attribute that wraps the view to its original size(Image size here)". However in Android we always use relative dimensions everywhere, and for a basic view like ImageView we would have to refer to the absolute size ! I find this is not good. Do I still miss something ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. When do you ever **have to** refer to absolute sizes with an `ImageView`?

Comment: in case no2 and no3. Or do I missunderstand and "absolute size != original size" ?

Comment: yes @Anthony Here is the point. As you know basically there does four types of the devices mdpi,hdpi, xhdpi,xxhdpi and ldpi is also there but is rarely seen. now during developing applicattion we do have all device compatible images. Hope you are understanding my point suppose in middle a small image say(100*100) image is to be shown. then you will find that i Image of size (100*100) will be seen good in low resolution device but for higher resolution devices you should have larger image. Now if you will give fixed size like 120*120 then 100*100 image would look stretched.

Comment: continuieng my last comment... so it is better to have the imge of size(120*120) and just pass imageView height width WRAP_CONTENT. Hope you have got my answer.